# CLion (C++) - No matching function

Tags: c++, clion

I use CLion just for coding, not compiling. I compile with an external tool and the program compiles as expected. However, I am getting a "No matching function" error in CLion when I call `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>.begin()` in order to get an iterator. It is strange because when I hit the autocomplete key, the method `begin()` appears as an option. See the attached images.

[image]

[image]

The error is annoying and if not solving it, I would like to know why this error appears. Maybe it is a misconfiguration. The C++ standard to use is set in the CMakeLists: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`. I've tried with 11 and 14 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a bug in CLion: [CPP-11511 Wrong error underlining when compare unordered_set "begin" and "end"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-11511). According to the comments, it applies to `unordered_map` as well.

Comment: I see. I also have the problem of casting `size_t` to `int`. It is definitely a bug. Thank you.